# UIScrollView behavior how to donot allow swipe horizontally when i need

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit

I need to make an app with scrollview. But i need an idea. I need to make uiscrollview that can swipe horizontally and vertically BUT when i go down i need to not allow swipe gorizontally. Is it possibly? and how? THank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `directionalLockEnabled` property of `UIScrollView` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually no. Cause when it is no i can't swipe at all directions.